# What is the difference between 'hegemony' and 'interpellation' in Marxism?

Tags: political-philosophy, marx, marxism

I thought that hegemony explains *how* one class exerts influence over another, and interpellation explains how one class *allows* the other class to exert influence over them. But then the two seem so similar.

Comment: It might be useful to add in some links for the terms; I haven't come across interpelation before.

Comment: [WP:Interpellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpellation_(philosophy)) might be helpful, I think it basically comes from Althusser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "hegemony" is usually associated with Gramsci (especially his [Prison Notebooks](http://www.marxists.org/archive/gramsci/prison_notebooks/)) and "interpellation" with Althusser ([Ideology and Ideological State Apparatuses](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/althusser/1970/ideology.htm)). The latter was influenced by the former. Both concepts are motivated by the same question: Why is it that the proletariat does not revolt as Marx predicted?

Hegemony could perhaps be conceived as a *state of affairs*: the success of the dominant class in making their view of the world (ideology) accepted and internalized by others as their own.

Interpellation, on the other hand, is a *process* of such internalization (subjectivation). Althusser writes that

> ideology ‘acts’ or ‘functions’ in such a way
>   that it ‘recruits’ subjects among the individuals (it recruits them
>   all), or ‘transforms’ the individuals into subjects (it transforms
>   them all) by that very precise operation which I have called
>   interpellation or hailing, and which can be imagined along the lines
>   of the most commonplace everyday police (or other) hailing: ‘Hey, you
>   there!'
>
> Assuming that the theoretical scene I have imagined takes place in the
>   street, the hailed individual will turn round. By this mere
>   one-hundred-and-eighty-degree physical conversion, he becomes a
>   subject. Why? Because he has recognized that the hail was ‘really’
>   addressed to him, and that ‘it was really him who was hailed’ (and not
>   someone else).

[A useful exposition of Gramsci's hegemony.](https://faculty.washington.edu/mlg/courses/definitions/hegemony.html) [A useful exposition of Althusser's interpellation.](http://www.longwood.edu/staff/mcgeecw/notesoninterpellation.htm)